# Why do some trading terminals use a reverse order book?

Tags: trading

I do not know what this is connected with, but I noticed that in terminals that are sharpened for stocks, futures and other stock markets, direct order books are used

[image]

but in foreign exchange terminals, the opposite (buyers are displayed at the top) with what it may be connected or here no explanation?

[image]

Comment: What is the name of the trading platform in the screenshots?

Comment: @Flux specifically the screenshots show the QUIK, but I saw it in the terminals of jp morgan, raiffeisen, ntpro, metatrader